# ZSH: glob with prefix

Tags: bash, zsh, globbing

Is it possible to add a 'prefix' to the shell glob expansion?
My use case is the following, I have a program which requires repeating the option flag to pass multiple files as input:

```
$ ls
foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt
$ ./some-script.sh -a foo.txt -a bar.txt -a baz.txt
```

I'd like to be able to use some kind of expansion to add `'-a '` to each item of `*txt`. Is that possible? with zsh? bash?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this in *zsh* using a so-called *glob qualifier* (see section *Glob Qualifiers* in the *zshexpn* man page):

```
./some-script.sh *.txt(P:-a:)
```

For the explanation I quote the manual:

> **P** ***string*** The  string will be prepended to each glob match as a
>   separate word.  string is delimited in the same way as arguments to
>   the e glob qualifier described above.  The qualifier can be repeated;
>   the words  are  prepended separately  so  that  the resulting command
>   line contains the words in the same order they were given in the list
>   of glob qualifiers.
>
> A typical use for this is to prepend an option before all occurrences
>   of a file name; for example, the  pat‐ tern `*(P:-f:)` produces the
>   command line arguments `-f file1 -f file2 ...`
>
> If the modifier ^ is active, then string will be appended instead of
>   prepended.  Prepending and appending is done  independently  so  both 
>   can  be  used  on  the  same  glob  expression;  for   example   by
>   writing `*(P:foo:^P:bar:^P:baz:)` which produces the command line
>   arguments `foo baz file1 bar ...`

To be cautious, check first with

```
$ print ./some-script.sh *.txt(P:-a:)
./some-script.sh -a foo.txt -a bar.txt -a baz.txt
```

if you get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I am expending @mpy answer for zsh in the case we do not want any spaces between the prefix and the filename, or if we also want a suffix,or any other string manipulation:

`print -l *.txt(e:'REPLY=PFX_${REPLY}_SFX':)`

which gives:

```
PFX_foo.txt_SFX
PFX_bar.txt_SFX
PFX_baz.txt_SFX
```

Note that the single quotes are important to avoid $REPLY being expanded prematurely.

For instance (even if `dd` will only process the last `if=` argument):

`dd *.img(e:'REPLY=if=$REPLY':)`

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-reply_002c-use-of